# How to change value of variable in theme file with functions.php Wordpress?

Tags: functions, excerpt

I want to change values of the variable in my theme. I don't want to edit in this file because after update theme, it will be lost.

So, I want to update values of this variable in functions.php.

In `post-simple.php` file:

```
<p class="from_the_blog_excerpt small-font show-next">
    <?php
    $excerpt      = get_the_excerpt();
    echo flatsome_string_limit_words( $excerpt, 15 );
    ?>
</p>
```

I want to change values `15(the length of string)` to another value in the function `flatsome_string_limit_words($excerpt, $length)`.

In `functions.php` of child theme, I write this code look like:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $excerpt, $length ) {
    $length = 30;
    return $length;
}
add_filter( 'flatsome_string_limit_words', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

I tried to change values of `$length` to values `30` instead of `15` like default set on `post-simple.php` file.

But it does not a success. It still return `$length = 15`.

Comment: consider to contact the developer of your theme; the function `flatsome_string_limit_words()` is theme specific, and the developer might be the best to help with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `flatsome_string_limit_words` hook exists inside the `string_limit_words` function?

I think your best option is to override whole `post-simple.php` template in your child, but even this depends on how is built the parent theme.

Comment: Sorry, typo mistake. I updated my question. `flatsome_string_limit_words`.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how filters works, take a look at codex page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/